# Trigger event when specific section is scrolled to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger an event when I scroll to a specific section NOT at a specific pixel amount. I have:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
   var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
   var scroll_pos_test = document.getElementById ('resume');             

   if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
       $("#backgroundimages").removeClass("bkg1").addClass("bkg2");
   } else {
   $("#backgroundimages").addClass("bkg1").removeClass("bkg2");
   }
});
```

If I change the var "scroll_pos_test" to a fixed pixel amount, it works.  But I want the event to trigger when I get to the "resume" section which depending on window size is not alway the same number of pixels down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [offset](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) top of your section:

```
var offsetSection = $( '.my_section' ).offset().top
```

and the on your scroll listener:

```
if( y_scroll_pos >= offsetSection) {
   // Here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

might I suggest [this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic) to you since it looks like you're already using jQuery.